jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive Connection and session is not closed
I am using spring-boot-starter-activemq to push messages to ActiveMQ.
When I run my code I expect temporary queue is created, and after I got response it should be deleted, but queue is not deleted after response. Every message that I send new queue is created and not deleted. When I close my application these queues are deleted.
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Override
public S sendAndReceive(T request) throws JmsMessagingException {
    try {
        String destinationQueueName = getDestinationQueueName();
        MessageCreator messageCreator = getMessageCreator(request);
        jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(10000);
        Message jmsResponseMessage = jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(destinationQueueName, messageCreator);

        return convertJmsMessage(jmsResponseMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        throw new JmsMessagingException(e);
    }
}


The connection and session are cached (by default) for performance reasons.

What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

AMQ version : 7.11.3 .
I use this dependency

org.springframework
spring-jms
5.3.37


Are you using Red Hat AMQ?

2.28.0.redhat-00011
